# What will happen if we call autorelease twice on a custom object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autorelease

**What will be the output of Calling autorelease twice over an custom object .
For iOS classes objects like NSString OS handles it . But what will happen to custom objects
**
Example :

```
Car *car = [[[[Car alloc]init]autorelease]autorelease];
```

Comment: Are you not using ARC? If not, why not?

Comment: @DonMag I came across this question in some interviews and online test thats why wanted to know , If anyone knows how it will behave and what will be the output.